# Azure function TargetFramework

Tags: .net-core, azure-functions, target-framework

[Recently dotnet core 2.2.7 has been released.](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/net-core-september-2019/)

I'm wondering, with regards to the runtime of Azure functions - will it automatically target this latest runtime?

I can't find any information about it in documentation or google search.

Comment: For now, it only update to 2.2.6.https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/releases/tag/v2.0.12612

Answer (score 1):

The article you've pointed to holds this chapter:

> **Azure App Services deployment**
>   Deployment of these updates Azure App Services has been scheduled, and they estimate completion by September 23, 2019.

My (very strong) guess is this includes Azure Functions.

The PR has been merged into `DEV` 6 days ago: https://github.com/Azure/azure-functions-host/pull/4936

EDIT:
The above is true and the update is rolling out now. Check this thread on twitter: https://twitter.com/rickvdbosch/status/1176074675778142209